# UIWebView inside UITableViewCell, link detected but not clickable

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have `UITableView` with one `UITableViewCell` subclass.
In that class I'm creating `UIWebView` and set the delegate to the class.
I'm also implementing `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

On loading the tableview, I call the cell.webView `loadHTMLString` with HTML string (not from the web).

After I call `loadHtmlString` the `shouldStartLoadWithRuquest` is called with navigationtype 5.
This also mean the delegate works OK.

Now, I can see the `UIWebView` with text and blue links, but when I click on the link the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is not called and nothing happen.

I read something about not implementing `UIWebView` in `UIScrollView`, but I also disable the scrolling of the `UIWebView`, I'm just using it as `UILabel` to display HTML text.

Any ideas why clicking on the link does not work and `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is not fire?

Comment: did you added "href" to the link

Comment: yep. when I test the uiwebView with loadHtmlString in new project, and add the uiwebview to uiviewcontroller(and not to uitableviewcell), 
the link worked and was clickable and event was fired.

Comment: UITableView may not be passing clicks to the UIWebView. As an idea (never done it), you can try to subclass UITableView in a manner that it does not swallow clicks.

Answer (score 2):

grrr.

answering my own question.

the UITableViewCell object  was set with userInteractionEnabled = NO in other place..

after changing to YES, it works. not my lucky day.

Comment: Hey thanks! I just made the same mistake... under very similar circumstances. Amazing.

Comment: In my case, UIWebView has userInteraction disabled by default. Thanks man!